# setting both a persistent and nonpersistent cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

so I know that I can set cookie in javascript using document.cookie and according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

> ;expires=date-in-GMTString-format If not specified it will expire at
>   the end of session

My question is, what if I want to set both a persistent cookie that expires at a specified date AND a session cookie that gets cleared the moment the session is closed?

What string should I set the document.cookie variable to in order to accomplish that?

Comment: Did you try to use multiple ``document.cookie=`` statements? Each statement should set another cookie - persistent or session based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for session only cookie use :

`document.cookie = "name=value;`

for persistent cookie use :

`document.cookie = "name=value; expires=some GMT date string";`